php file gets deleted by cpanel after saving
I have a header.php file. As soon as I save that file, it disappears from cPanel within a couple of seconds. Note, that I am not even running the php file at all.
I was able to isolate a few lines of code in this header.php that was causing the deletion.
As soon as I type below 4 lines of code and save the file, the file gets deleted. This file has about 500+ lines of code.
if (substr_count($uri_path, 'index')>0){
            $uri_path = str_replace("index", "!", $uri_path);
            $url_path='index.php';
        }

Below is some of the lines of code that precedes the above code.
$url_path=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$position=strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/');
$uri_path= substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,$position).'/';
// *** url_rewrite ***
if ($humo_option["url_rewrite"]=="j"){
   $uri_path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

I believe cPanel is detecting it as some kind of security threat and deleting it.

You'll probably need to contact your host, or cPanel directly. It could be a security feature on the server, it could be a bug (or feature!) of cPanel

Is the whole file getting completely removed, or is it being reverted to its original state? Are you sure it's cpanel that's doing the change? I.e., perhaps it's something else that's changing the file, and cpanel is just showing you its current state. Can you edit the file, save some other minimal change (like adding a comment), and the file remains?

Check the file permission in your cPanel. I hope this will help you. Cheers!

Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer
